# How to use slimscroll for a specific portion in a table?

Tags: jquery, slimscroll

Details: Im using jquery slimscroll in my application and it works fine. But the problem I am facing is that,when I try to implement the slimscroll inside a table, the scroll bar overlaps with the table heading too. I just want the scroll to be visible in the table body section only.
 Here is my html:

```
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6  col-lg-4">
                    <div  class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table col-md-12 table-striped table-condensed cf">
                            <thead class="cf">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Select</th>
                                    <th>Page</th>
                                    <th>Count</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="pageDetails-1" class="slimScrollPage">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

Here the class "slimScrollPage" is the one, im using to initiate the slimscroll. I have tried changing the positions of the "slimScrollPage" class to various positions,but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jscrollpane 
for refrence please see the below link
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/